# SimpleCursorAdapder load only visible items

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I use custom adapter, which extended SimpleCursorAdadapter. When all items in listview can be visible in screen all works ok, but if items count more than can contain in screen, item position is repeating (for example i click on first item, first hide item is activated too)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    DB db;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context,layout,c,from,to);
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        ImageView marker = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_productiviry_img);
        TextView prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvMarker);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 10)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.productive);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 7)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 12)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.unproductive);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call super.bindView if you are overriding it.

Comment: I need, because without calling super.bindView doesn't loading items content